# How to send ajax request in Datatables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have used this `ignited_datatables` https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables in my `CodeIgniter project`. It successfully returns `data` from the `database`. But the main `problem` is that when I add a `new record` the newly inserted data is not shown in the table `automatically` and when I `refresh` the page then the `newly inserted` data is then shown in the `table`. so I want to show that data automatically through `ajax` and I have not to `refresh` the page.

**My View**

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
    <table id="Slider_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Title</th>
           <th>item_Price</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

**This Script is Inside the View**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Slider_table").dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": "json",
                "type"    : "POST",
                "url"     : "'.base_url().'Home/items_list/list",
                "data"    : aoData,
                "success" : function(res){

                 fnCallback(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: what you mean by automatically display data??

Comment: Means I want to fetch data through ajax.

Comment: U can fetch data througn ajax .You cannot push data to the client, ever. Servers responds to requests from the client.

If it is actually critical to do this update, you need to timestamp or otherwise identify the last time data was added to the database.

Then, use setInterval and ajax to pass this timestamp to the server. If they timestamp does not match, return the new data and reload your table.

Note: this has side effects like not letting the serverside session die until the browser is closed or added traffic to the server.

Comment: that means you can reload ajax request in every time intervel to reload table!

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR So how can I do that?

Comment: look my answer,

Comment: are you inserting data in same data listing page ?

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya yes

Comment: are you inserting with ajax if yes then return data from there and on success manipulate html table , no need to set time intervel ?

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya How to do that?

Comment: inside success of insertion ajax  put the code given by @H45H in answer, just replace some data with your data (if you are using bootstrap data table) or create custom html and append it

Comment: so after inserting function call ,call datatable function ones, you dont want ajax reload ii intervels, am updated my answer! please give more details in question ,please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use **draw()**  method after success in order to have the table's display updated.

```
    table.row.add( {
            //you dynamic data
            "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
            "position":   "System Architect",
            "salary":     "$3,120",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office":     "Edinburgh",
            "extn":       "5421"
        } ).draw();
```

as per documentation. please refer [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

Comment: And Where I can write this?

Comment: after getting response from server side. in `success` function. you will add this.

Comment: Ok I will check it.

Comment: And what is this "name" you mentioned in the code? is that a column name in the Datatable?

Comment: Now it gives error "Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined" in console

Comment: Yes, it should give because there is no `table` defined. I ve given you an example for what you have to do. not exactly your dynamic code. please refer the link mentioned above. also you have to define your `table` i.e
`var table = $("#Slider_table").dataTable( { .... } )` it ll remove that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax.reload() method

```js
     var i=1;
     
     function datatable()
     {  
    $("#myTable1").dataTable().fnDestroy();
  
         $('#myTable1').DataTable({
             "ordering": true,
             "searching": true,
             "bPaginate": true,
   ajax: 'myajaxURL.php', 
   columns : [
     { "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return i++;   }
       },
     {"data": "col1"},
     {"data": "col2"},
     {"data": "col3"},
    ]
});
     }
     
function insertData { 
      //after each insertion do this
     var i=1;
     $('#myTable1').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
      //after each insertion do this
}
     $(document).ready(function () {
    
     datatable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i always did this in every view of my page

```
 var table;
 table = $('#Slider_table').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,            // OPTIONAL
    "bSorting": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
 });
   function getData() {

     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url('your_controler/function_name'); ?>",
     data: aoData,
     error: function(response) {
       alert('Error')
     },
    success: function(response) {
       setTable(response);
    }
  });
 }

 function setTable(response) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(response);
   var t = $('#Slider_table').dataTable();
   t.clear().draw();
   $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
        var a = value.a;
        var b = value.b;
        var c = value.c;
        t.row.add([
           a,
           b,
           c
        ]).draw(false);  
   })
 }
```

So everytime you reload or insert a new data,you just have to call ***getData()*** function to load a new set of data you just insert. And ***t.clear().draw();*** will clear all data from tbody,and replaced it with new one . Hope this helps