# Refresh jquery data table without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to refresh the jquery datatable every 3 seconds. I already done this but I have pagination issues. When I execute the code the pagination is gone so all the data is display without pagination.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="timexx">
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-right:-10px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id #</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
      include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');

      $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts_tic WHERE statuss = 'New' OR statuss = 'On-Process' order by id DESC")or die(mysqli_error());
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name'];

        ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $id;?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $name;?>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <?php }?>
  </table>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#timexx').load(location.href + " #timexx>*", "")
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: You might want to look into using `ajax` Here is jQuery's [**$.ajax({}); Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: use ajax call in dataTable() and use ajax.reload() in setintervel - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55390352/9042437

Comment: @phantom - hi, did my answer help you?

Comment: @billynoah it will show the data but not inside the data table . Please help me

Comment: @phantom - I'm not sure what you mean.  My answer specifically reloads the data into the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an ajax data source along with [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).  In fact, the docs page I linked there has an example of just what you are after.

For your markup you can simply create the table and header:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-right:-10px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Then initialize datatables with ajax data source, declare your columns and start the loop:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
        "ajax" : 'http://example.com/table_data.php',
        "columns" : [
            { "data" : "id" },
            { "data" : "name" )
        ]
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        // the second argument here will prevent the pagination
        // from reseting when the table is reloaded
        table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    }, 3000);
});
```

Now you need a web page at the endpoint declared for your ajax data source `http://example.com/table_data.php` that spits out the table data as a json.  There are a few ways this can be structured, but my preference is to use the `data` property as [the docs state:](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

> *the data parameter format shown here can be used with a simplified DataTables initialisation as data is the default property that DataTables looks for in the source data object.*

With this objective, your php script might look something like this:

```
include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts_tic WHERE statuss = 'New' OR statuss = 'On-Process' order by id DESC") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$results = [];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results['data'][] = [
        'id'   => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name']
    ];
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

*Side note, [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) expects a single argument which should be your connection resource.*